# [Android][Renderscript] passing 'rs_script' (aka 'struct rs_script') to parameter of incompatible type 'rs_kernel' (aka 'void *')

Tags: android, rs

When trying to run app with render script on Android N device - I get only this error

```
error:passing 'rs_script' (aka 'struct rs_script') to parameter of incompatible type 'rs_kernel' (aka 'void *')
```

But the same project runs in android 6 without any error. Also I can generate the apk file but in Android N it crashes.

Here is the issue it gives -

```
rs_script gScript;
void filter() {
    rsForEach(gScript, gIn, gOut);  
}
...
```

gradle configuration

```
defaultConfig {
        .....
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        renderscriptTargetApi 18
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
```

and proguard rules

```
-keep class public
-keep class android.support.v8.renderscript.** { *; }
```

I have tried to with different `renderscriptTargetApi` 24 or 22 but it keeps on giving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In default configuration I changed `targetSdkVersion 21`. Because I was trying to run the app  in 7.0.0 (android 24). It worked.